# FindMaximum returns a solution that violates the constraints

Tags: bugs, mathematical-optimization

I am looking at the following optimization problem

$$
\begin{align*}
\max\ & 1000 r_1 + \frac{1}{2}r_2 + \frac{1}{3}r_3\\
\text{s.t. }& 1000^2 r_1 + \frac{1}{4}r_2 + \frac{1}{9}r_3 = \frac{1}{9},\\
& 1000^2 p_1 + \frac{1}{4}p_2 + \frac{1}{9}p_3 = \frac{1}{9},\\
& r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + r_4 = 2\\
& p_1 + p_2 + p_3 + p_4 = 2\\
& 0\leq p_i\leq 1,\quad i = 1,\dots,4\\
& r_i^2\leq p_i,\quad i = 1,\dots,4
\end{align*}
$$
with the following Mathematica code (it is clear that $r_1=p_1=0$, $r_2=p_2=0$, $r_3=p_3=1$, $r_4=p_4=1$ is a feasible solution so I picked it to be the initial solution)

```
FindMaximum[{1000 r1 + 1/2 r2 + 1/3 r3, 
  {1000^2 r1 + 1/4 r2 + 1/9 r3 == 1/9, 
   r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 == 2, 
   r1^2 <= p1, r2^2 <= p2, r3^2 <= p3, r4^2 <= p4, 
   1000^2 p1 + 1/4 p2 + 1/9 p3 == 1/9, 
   p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == 2,
   0 <= p1 <= 1, 0 <= p2 <= 1, 0 <= p3 <= 1, 0 <= p4 <= 1}
  }, 
  {{r1, 0}, {r2, 0}, {r3, 1}, {r4, 1}, {p1, 0}, {p2, 0}, {p3, 1}, {p4, 1}}, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

Mathematica returns the following answer

```
{0.45521, {r1 -> -6.30073*10^-8, r2 -> 0.268328, r3 -> 0.963328, 
  r4 -> 0.768345, p1 -> 0., p2 -> 0.0719999, p3 -> 0.928, p4 -> 1.}}
```

If you look at the constraint that $1000^2 p_1 + \frac{1}{4}p_2 + \frac{1}{9}p_3 = \frac{1}{9}$, you can see that in the solution Mathematica returns,
the left-hand side evaluates to $0.12111\cdots$, so the constraint is not satisfied.

Is this a bug or just a numerical inaccuracy? Just the value seems too large compared with $1/9$ -- the additive error is not at the scale of $10^{-4}$ or $10^{-5}$.

Comment: Yes, I can reproduce that, it fails these conditions `{r1^2 <= p1, 1000000 p1 + p2/4 + p3/9 == 1/9, p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == 2}`, with the largest error on the one you mentioned.

Comment: I think `r1^2 <= p1` and `p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == 2` are pretty minor violations, as the additive error is around $10^{-4}$ or $10^{-5}$, which is understandably to be usual precision problem. But the constraint I pointed out is too big to be called a precision problem.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a bug. If you define the `error` variable like this

```
sol = FindMaximum[{
   1000 r1 + 1/2 r2 + 1/3 r3,
   {
    1000^2 r1 + 1/4 r2 + 1/9 r3 == 1/9,
    r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 == 2,
    r1^2 <= p1,
    r2^2 <= p2,
    r3^2 <= p3,
    r4^2 <= p4,
    1000^2 p1 + 1/4 p2 + 1/9 p3 == 1/9,
    error == 1000^2 p1 + 1/4 p2 + 1/9 p3 - 1/9, (* just change this *)
    p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == 2,
    0 <= p1 <= 1, 0 <= p2 <= 1, 0 <= p3 <= 1, 0 <= p4 <= 1}
   }, {{r1, 0}, {r2, 0}, {r3, 1}, {r4, 1}, {p1, 0}, {p2, 0}, {p3, 
    1}, {p4, 1}, {error, 0}}, AccuracyGoal -> 10]
```

you get the same solution:

```
{0.45521, {r1 -> -6.30073*10^-8, r2 -> 0.268328, r3 -> 0.963328, 
  r4 -> 0.768345, p1 -> 0., p2 -> 0.0719999, p3 -> 0.928, p4 -> 1., 
  error -> 5.75352*10^-18}}
```

however

```
1000^2 p1 + 1/4 p2 + 1/9 p3 - 1/9 /. Last[sol]
 error /. Last[sol]
```

yields

```
0.00999999
5.75352*10^-18
```

although clearly the two figures should be identical. I suggest you contact Wolfram.

Comment: Thanks! Contacted Wolfram. Confirmed as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I don't find it a bug. The feasible set consists of  only one element

```
Reduce[{1000^2 r1 + 1/4 r2 + 1/9 r3 == 1/9, r1 + r2 + r3 + r4 == 2,
r1^2 <= p1, r2^2 <= p2, r3^2 <= p3, r4^2 <= p4, 1000^2 p1 + 1/4 p2 + 1/9 p3 == 1/9, 
p1 + p2 + p3 + p4 == 2, 0 <= p1 <= 1, 0 <= p2 <= 1, 0 <= p3 <= 1, 0 <= p4 <= 1},
 {r1, r2,  r3, r4, p1, p2, p3, p4}, Reals]
```

> r1 == 0 && r2 == 0 && r3 == 1 && r4 == 1 && p1 == 0 && p2 == 0 && 
>    p3 == 1 && p4 == 2 - p3

and Mathematica does her best.